# I want to put a circle inside a circle but the issue is my first layer circle is cropped from the top and left

Tags: html, css

```css
#pcircle {
    
    left: 50%;
    position:absolute;
  }
#icircle {
    
  left: 50%;
  position:absolute;
 
 
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<p style="position: absolute; bottom: 20px; left: 700px;z-index: 2;">
         <a name="anchor"></a>

            <svg id="pcircle" width="850" height="850" viewBox="0 0 850 850" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <circle cx="350" cy="350" r="425" fill="#552626"/>
            </svg>
            <svg id="icircle" width="700" height="700" viewBox="0 0 700 700" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <circle cx="350" cy="350" r="350" fill="#CD5353" fill-opacity="0.78"/>
            </svg>

   </p>
   </html>
```

Comment: cx="425" cy="425"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVG's content is out of `viewBox`, so it was cropped.

[viewBox - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox)

And here the corrent version of code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
  svg {
    position: absolute;
  }
</style>
<p>
  <svg width="850" height="850" viewBox="0 0 850 850">
    <circle cx="425" cy="425" r="425" fill="#552626" />
  </svg>
  <svg width="850" height="850" viewBox="0 0 850 850">
    <circle cx="425" cy="425" r="350" fill="#CD5353" fill-opacity="0.78" />
  </svg>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your circle is cropped because it's the full size of the SVG but it isn't centered.

- The viewBox is an 850px square.
- Your circle has a radius of 425 giving it an 850px diameter.
- The circle's center is at (350, 350), which is 75px up and left of center.

So it renders partially outside the bounding box, hence the "cropping".

Comment: ughh, thank for your help really apreciate it.